# Guidance in connecting multiple machines to a single blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

I'm seeking guidance with respect to the execution of a private blockchain. I have created a private blockchain using geth and deployed the contract using truffle. I am looking for a solution that helps you connect all machines to the same blockchain. I am using macbook pro and the im unable to host the blockchain on local server port 8545. Have replaced the rpc flag with http as the current version of geth does not support rpc. Can anyone help me with this issue?